# Use Alias only for parameters in function

Tags: function, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

How can i use alias only when i call my cmdlet function ?

This is my code

```
Function Deploy-Citrix {
[cmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
Param(

 [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
 [Alias("component")]
 [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$componentparam,

 [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
 [Alias("ip")]
 [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$ipaddressparam,
        )
```

In this case for the second parameter for example, i can use the alias `-ip` but i can also use `-ipaddressparam`.

```
Deploy-citrix -componentparam "toto" -ipaddressparam "172.22.0.100"
Deploy-citrix -component "toto" -ip "172.22.0.100"
```

I can use both, but i want to disable the first one, i want to have alias only.

I know i can rename my variable, but i don't want to touch them in the whole script.

How can i achieve that?

I'm using Powershell V4.0

Thanks

Comment: Why would you create a function with a parameter name that you don't want to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is disallow the long form, you have no choice but to rename the parameter and remove the alias.

To minimize changes to your script, you can create a variable inside the function, e.g.

```
Function Deploy-Citrix {
    [cmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$ip)

    $ipaddressparam = $ip
    ...
```